# RHEL Bash Script for R Shiny Pubishing

Tags: r, linux, bash, rhel

I'm trying to make a bash script that will automate the commands for me to publish some content on a R Shiny Server.

While logged in as root I enter the following line by line:

```
cd /opt/shiny-server/samples/sample-apps
rm -R -f existingDirectory4Application
cd /home/Username
mv Directory4ApplicationNew /opt/shiny-server/samples/sample-apps
cd /opt/shiny-server/samples/sample-apps
chmod -R 777 NewDirectory4Application
systemctl restart shiny-server
```

To make it easier for publishing I name the directories the same name; like shinyApp.

So far this is my script, but I keep getting errors. I want to be able to pass the script the argument of the directory that has the application files I want to publish:

```
#!/bin/bash

dashboard=$1
cd /opt/shiny-server/samples/sample-apps
rm -R -f $dashboard
cd /home/Username
mv $dashboard /opt/shiny-server/samples/sample-apps
cd /opt/shiny-server/samples/sample-apps
chmod -R 777 $dashboard
systemctl restart shiny-server
echo "Server has been restarted and Dashboard is now Published"
```

The errors I get are the following:

```html
sh PubExisting.sh shinyApp
PubExisting.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
: No such file or directory /opt/shiny-server/samples/sample-apps
: No such file or directory /home/Username
mv: cannot stat ‘shinyApp\r’: No such file or directory
: No such file or directory /opt/shiny-server/samples/sample-apps
chmod: cannot access ‘shinyApp\r\r’: No such file or directory
Failed to restart shiny-server\x0d.service: Unit not found.
Server has been restarted and Dashboard is now Published
```

Any help would be very much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Looks like you wrote your script from DOS editor which has CRLF endings which your Unix/Linux machien doesn't like. Clean it up by running `dos2unix PubExisting.sh`

Comment: I got the error "command not found" for dos2unix.

I did make it in notepad though and just changed the extension to .sh

Comment: Then used WinSCP to transfer it over to the server.